# Can I write more than one structure in file?

Tags: cobol

I have FD

```
   FD  CR1
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
       DATA RECORDS ARE FIRSTSTR, SECONDSTR, THIRDSTR.
```

and 3 structures

```
   01  FIRSTSTR.
       05 FIRSTFIVE       PIC X(05).
       05 SECONDFIVE       PIC X(05).

   01  SECONDSTR.
       05 FIRSTTWO       PIC X(02).
       05 SECONDONE       PIC X(01).
       05 THIRDFOUR       PIC X(04).

   01  THIRDSTR.
       05 FIRSTTHREE       PIC X(03).
       05 SECONDTHREE       PIC X(03).
       05 THIRDTHREE       PIC X(03).
```

Can I write all info in file like this:

```
WRITE FIRSTSTR, SECONDSTR, THIRDSTR.
```

And read from file in 3 structures like this:

```
READ CR1 INTO FIRSTSTR, SECONDSTR, THIRDSTR AT END
```

Comment: Your FD is OK, but your READ and WRITE statements are not standard COBOL.  You'll have to do the I-O one record at a time.

Comment: It would be good to know which specific COBOL compiler and OS you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write more than one type of record to a file, but no, you can't do it the way you want to.

The record-definitions (structures) under the `FD` all occupy the same storage, meaning the all the 01-levels start at the same byte address. The individual records cannot simultaneously contain different data.

This is called an "implicit REDEFINES".

The `READ ... INTO ...` is to read and at the same time copy the current record to the INTO item (singular) that you specify. The INTO item would usually be in the `WORKING-STORAGE` (although they could also be in `LOCAL-STORAGE`). It would be exotic to use the `LINKAGE SECTION` and very, very, odd to use something in the `FILE SECTION` as a target for a `READ ... INTO...`.

You only `READ` one record at a time. Unless you file has a set, fixed-in-stone, sequence of different records, we'd usually `READ` the file, identify the record, and then process that particular type of record.

You can only specify one receiving item for `READ ... INTO ...` and only one source item for `WRITE ... FROM ...`.